# asp.net mvc tree view with checkbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Ok I am looking for a solution in mvc2 where i can have tree view generated where after that i can checked the nodes I want to enter the value in the database. Can anyone point me to something?

Basically I am assigning features to a particular group.(I have a group admin whom I can assign the manage user add edit delete,manage groups delete,manage teacher add edit feature Can someone point me to some other technique that i can implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [telerik treeview control for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/treeview.aspx). It is also available in an open-source version from [the CodePlex website](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/).